# Regex or lastIndexOf when removing last instance of a string

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I couldn't apply answers to other similar questions (trying to replace the last occurrence of a string) because I am having trouble with the syntax.

I'm trying to replace the last occurrence of a string. The value of the string is stored in a variable that is passed to the `.replace()` method like this:

```
var str += some additive strings;
var del = a string that lives within str; // the value is dynamic

str = str.replace(del$, ''); // this doesn't work to remove the last occurrence of `del` in str
```

As I understand it the `$` argument looks for the last occurrence of a string within a regex; but I can't figure out how to use it alongside a variable passed to `.replace()`. Any suggestions?

Comment: `$` in a regex means the end of the string, so your attempt will remove `del` if it occured at the very end of the string. It Also you need to wrap regex's in brackets, so it'd be `replace(/del$/, '')`

Comment: Won't that just look for the string `del`, not the string value contained within the `variable del`?

Comment: Ah yes it will, my mistake. In that case you'd want `new RegExp(del + '$')`, but it still stands that `$` in the regex is not doing what you want it to do. If I understand correctly, if you want to remove say the last "foo", then you'd want `"a foo b c foo d e"` to become `"a foo b c  d e"`, right?

Comment: Yes. The twist is that the string `foo` in your example, would be assigned to the variable `del` programmatically. Say, the user makes a list, and wants to remove the last thing they added. So the value of `del` that must be removed is dynamically changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use the RegExp with a $, do it like this:

```
var str += 'some additive strings';
var re = new RegExp('a string that lives within str$');
str = str.replace(re, '');
```

Comment: Thanks - to clarify, the string to remove is not static. It is dynamically assigned to the variable `del`, based on some user choices. Say they make a list that repeats some of the strings, I want them to be able to remove the last string they added.

Comment: Then try the above with re=new RegExp(del + '$')

Comment: That also works well. I'll play around with your answer and @AmitJoki's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lastIndexOf()` with `slice()`

Example:

```
var str ="HI this is cool isn't it? cool";
var del='cool';// put whatever here
var index = test.lastIndexOf(del);
var length=del.length;
if(index!=-1)
var removeStr=test.substr(index,length);    
str.replace(removeStr,''); // HI this is cool isn't it?
```

Mate, this is just an answer. You'll need to use it according to your needs.

**Updated** Live demo:http://jsfiddle.net/n2Kgn/2

Comment: thanks, but that's not quite what I"m looking for. I want to assign the string to remove within a variable called `del`. The string may be different based on user choices. But, it will always be present within `str`. So I want to remove the last instance of the string contained within `del`, from what resides in `str`. Not the word `del` per se.

Comment: @user1837608, check out the demo

Comment: It's not quite correct, it assumes that the text is at the very end of the string. See my comment up under the question.

Comment: @AmitJoki I understand now - it works just like your fiddle suggests. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @MattGreer, what difference does it make? lastIndexOf() returns the last word. Go on check out the demo given and type your test case of `"a foo b c foo d e"` and type `"foo"` in the word box and click done.

Comment: @user1837608, you should mark my answer as answer, so it helps others

Comment: @AmitJoki yes and your solution is wrong. If I put in `a b c foo d foo e`, your solution gives `a b c foo d`, there is no `e` when there should be.

Comment: @MattGreer, check it out mate.

Comment: This is a lot of work to find 'removeStr', when all it will ever do is equal the initial value of 'del' (if found). In the end, it is not much different than writing str.replace(del,''). Except in this case, if you *don't* find a match it will actually remove the wrong characters. You could rewrite this to say "if (index!=-1) str = str.substr(0,index)" and delete the last 3 lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

```
str = str.substring(0, str.length - del.length);
```